# tabular extend beyond a page

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have a large dataset to show in tabular format. The problem is that it doesn't page  break into more pages. And the excess is not being displayed.

This is how i used the tabular tag

```
 \begin{tabular}{ lllllllllllllllll }

00000000 & 00 & 01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\ 
00000016 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 \\ 
00000032 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 \\ 
00000048 & 48 & 49 & 50 & 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 & 55 & 56 & 57 & 58 & 59 & 60 & 61 & 62 & 63 \\ 
00000064 & 64 & 65 & 66 & 67 & 68 & 69 & 70 & 71 & 72 & 73 & 74 & 75 & 76 & 77 & 78 & 79 \\ 
00000080 & 80 & 81 & 82 & 83 & 84 & 85 & 86 & 87 & 88 & 89 & 90 & 91 & 92 & 93 & 94 & 95 \\ 
    \end{tabular}
```

I haven't included all the rows here.

How can i make it automatically page break into new pages and show the entire table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `{tabular}` to `{longtable}` and load the longtable package.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [`supertabular`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/supertabular) packages.